# Updated International patent protection index from Park (2008)

Tags: reference-request, intellectual-property

[Park (2008)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0048733308000231) provides an international patent protection index between the years of 1960-2005 with 5 years intervals. I was wondering if an updated version of such an index exist?

Comment: What solution did you use in the end?

Comment: @cfp Honestly, I did not continue the study.

Comment: I've since discovered that there is updated data available on this page: http://fs2.american.edu/wgp/www/ after the "Research policy" paper. Direct link: http://fs2.american.edu/wgp/www/Patent%20index1960%20-%202015.xlsx

Comment: This is a good news!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently not. A [2015 article](http://fs2.american.edu/wgp/www/GER2015.pdf) by the [author](http://fs2.american.edu/wgp/www/) uses his index to evaluate economic growth across country and time, stopping in 2005, same as the index in the original paper. And yet, many of the other variables are in principle available for more recent years.

The first best here would be for you to [contact the author](http://www.american.edu/cas/faculty/wgp.cfm). He might be in the process of updating his index. Actually, if you look into [his working papers](http://www.american.edu/cas/faculty/wgp.cfm), you can see he is doing some work on patents. Even more, there he offers some (more updated) data on [copyright](http://fs2.american.edu/wgp/www/intl%20copyright.xlsx) and [Trademark](http://fs2.american.edu/wgp/www/intl%20tmark.xls). You might contact him to know better what this is.

The second best is that you expand the index yourself. For example, you can use the data just mentioned. Alternatively, you can use the **subcomponents** of [this](https://www.fraserinstitute.org/economic-freedom/dataset?year=2014&page=dataset&min-year=2&max-year=0&filter=0&most-free=1&quartile2=1&quartile3=1&least-free=1) or [this](http://www.heritage.org/index/explore) index (e.g. property rights or investor protection). There are more indexes [here](http://www3.weforum.org/docs/CSI/2012-13/GCR_Pillar1_2012-13.pdf) (e.g. intellectual property protection), and [here](http://internationalpropertyrightsindex.org/).

One way to do this update is to take the original Park's series, and see which one of the above match its better (higher correlation, for instance). From here you obtain your "proxy". Then, simply extend Park's index with the newest data on this proxy. This is simply an exercise of "concatenation".

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. This file goes up to 2015: http://fs2.american.edu/wgp/www/Patent%20index1960%20-%202015.xlsx 
If this link no longer works, it should be linked from this page: http://fs2.american.edu/wgp/www after the "Research policy" paper.